# Почему нету протокола https на stackoverflow.com?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, https

Почему нету протокола https на stackoverflow.com?
Он же вроде был, так почему его убрали?

Comment: он есть. а подобный вопрос надо задавать на Meta

Comment: а почему редиректа нету? Вроде же раньше был. Понятно спасибо.

Comment: А я вот за http. И не нужен мне редирект.

Comment: вы хотя бы тут удалите вопрос. а то на мете задали, а этот тут уже закрывают  и в причине закрытия указывают перенос на мету

Comment: Несколько минут назад переключили на https здесь и на англоязычном Stack Overflow. Спасибо.